# How can I change DNS providers without needing to type in my password?

Tags: network, wifi, dns

On Mac OS X Yosemite, you need to enter in your password to change DNS entries. Otherwise the entries are all greyed out.

[image: mac password greyed]

I change DNS frequently (Gogo Inflight among others doesn't work with custom DNS resolvers) and I'm the only person that uses my computer. Is there a setting I can flip to disable password protection?

Comment: Are you using an admin account? I need no p/w to change mine

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I have access to `sudo` etc by typing in my password.

Comment: Are you using Yosemite?

Comment: Yes, I have an admin account.

Comment: @Tetsujin `sudo` isn’t `root`. it’s any account that’s able to `su` to `root` and act on its behalf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The account you are logged in as needs to be configured as an admin account, because the DNS settings affect all users on the system, not just the current user.  If it is not an admin account, then you will need to authenticate every time you want to change the DNS settings.

If you are logged in using admin account and still have the problem, then open System Preferences, go to Security & Privacy, click the "Advanced..." button, and make sure that "Require an administrator password to access system-wide preferences" is not enabled.